# How to achieve overlap in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to achieve this layout :

[image]

This is the code i tried :

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow_bg"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/crown"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/position_no_bg"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But I am getting this output : 
[image]

And the problem is that as I decrease the screen size, I get issue of the crown moving from its position. My main issue is that the crown is not able to set in place.

These are the images :

[image: crown]
[image: bg]
[image]

EDIT :

Adding 2 constraints for crown :

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow_bg"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:src="@drawable/crown"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/position_no_bg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT 2 :

Tried this code again, and got good response but the design is moving in 7.0" plus devices:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow_without_crown"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/crown"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.04"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/position_no_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>







    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use Framelayout and RelativeLayout

Comment: Not able to achieve the exact result with those, if you have any idea please do help me

Comment: provide me image link i ll try

Comment: can you please share your drawables i will try at my side

Comment: added the graphics

Comment: **1** - The "circle" and the "bar" should be a **single piece** (possibly, a **`9 patch`**). **2** - Put the "crown" in the same place where the bar is and give the bar some "transparent space" on top (it could simply be some **padding**), so to accomodate the extra crown height.

Comment: @ParthAnjaria see the answer below I think its similar to what you trying

Answer (score 2):

Try this may solve your problem

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/yellow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:src="@drawable/crown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, this is working on different screen sizes make a try

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: @ParthAnjaria check this updated answer may works. this working on android studio Device Editor. so please make a try

Answer (score 0):

You are applying absolute positions for your crown, this is why the crown stays where it is when you change the screen size.

The crown image is not attached to the other graphics.

i.e. set the crowns bottom constraint to the bottom border of your `yellow_bg`image and increase the bottom margin

Edit:
This is how it could fit in your question - you have to remove the white space around your background image!!

- set background constraint to bottom and left of parent.
- set the
  circle to the bottom and left of the background -

  - after that i set the crown on top of the background.
  - it floats now above because your
    image has a huhe white border. you need to adjust that.

you need to adjust it finally with margins.

```js
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/yellow_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/crown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/position_no_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/bg"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: adding bottom constaint, but cant keep the image handing with one constaint, it still moves. have to give two constraint, where do i give the second constraint. added my code if i add constrains which i still dont get output.